# Get DTC Active Transactions (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, msdtc

I'm writing some Powershell scripts so we can monitor our SQLServer instances through Nagios, I need to get the DTC Active Transaction count in PS so I can output it to Nagios. Is this possible? If so how do I do it?

I'm very much a Windows/Powershell n00b so sorry if this is a basic question. Most of the params I need seem to be avaliable with 'Get-Counter' but this one doesn't seem to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the performance counters directly from Nagios using `check_nrpe` instead:

```
$USER1$/check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.123 -p 5666 -c CheckCounter -a "Counter:DTCTx=\Distributed Transaction Coordinator\Active Transactions" ShowAll  MaxWarn=100 MaxCrit=150
```

This assumes that `$USER1$` points to your Nagios `libexec` folder.

You'd need to set `MaxWarn` and `MaxCrit` to thresholds that meet your own alerting requirements.